# If I copy my Tor relay image for a friend does it help?

Tags: relays

I know it will start and connect but the fingerprint is the same.. does that matter?

Comment: Ive got the image for a raspberry pi. Would like my friend to plug and play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that matters. The fingerprint is what Tor uses to build reputation (e.g. flags). I'm not sure what the Tor network would do if it found two nodes with the same fingerprint, but in any case, clients using your relays would not be able to differentiate between the two systems.

If you want to help your lazy friend, image your relay, delete all the files in the Tor directory, and modify the name of the relay in the torrc file. When the service starts for the first time, it will re-generate the keys under a different name but be functionally the same.

Comment: Please can you elaborate. If I delete all the files in the Tor directory doesnt that delete the torrc file?

Comment: And how do I do that without starting it up? Open sdcard on another system and manually delete the files?